# how to automate click event and combobox selection of any windows application using vb scripts

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBScript, I need to automate click events to some buttons using its class or id ctrl attribute and select specific option from combo box list. I already have the control attributes like class name or id using which I have to automate different events to the windows applications using vb script.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "calc"
```

now I have to do addition of 5 and 6, I have respective ids as num5Button(5), plusButton(+), num6Button(6) and equalButton(=). I need perform click operation for this button. How should I do this?

Comment: Share your code and let us know exactly where you are facing an issue

Comment: for calculator operation: Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "calc" now I have to do addition of 5 and 6, I have respective ids as num5Button(5), plusButton(+), num6Button(6) and equalButton(=). I need perform click operation for this button. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are automating Calculator, you can use [`SendKeys`](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) to automate the math functions. Sample code is

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "calc"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.AppActivate "Calculator"
WshShell.SendKeys "5{+}"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "6"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

I would recommend using something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for automating basic Window GUI operations.

Comment: thanks Pankaj, but calculator is one of an example but actually i need to pass click control to other application buttons where I cant pass sendkeys and also cant I automate without using autoit?

Comment: Yes. You can use sendkeys method to click buttons, enter text in text boxes. Try with notepad.